# Install TOR Browser on CentOS 6.4?

Tags: centos, tor

I've been trying to install the TOR bundle on my fresh install of CentOS but I've found that most repos are outdated and/or not working. Anyone know a simple way of installing it for CentOS 6.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the latest Tor Browser Bundle [from their homepage](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).

Once you've unpacked it, run it via the following command, executed from the directory where you extracted the files to:

```
./start-tor-browser
```

Answer (score 1):

**EL5 packages** (CentOS 5-6)

Packages for RHEL 5 (and clones) are signed with different key due to old rpm limitations, put this repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory:

```
[tor]
name=Tor experimental repo
enabled=1
baseurl=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/el/5/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-torproject.org.EL5.asc

[tor-source]
name=Tor experimental source repo
enabled=1
autorefresh=0
baseurl=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/el/5/SRPMS
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/rpm/RPM-GPG-KEY-torproject.org.EL5.asc
```

Fingerprint of RPM-GPG-KEY-torproject.org.EL5.asc key above should be:

```
9D27 0E2A 351C B4CB 6D95  78AF F8E7 95F8 B4D4 03EA
```

Package installation and running

Once you have the repo file, install Tor using (yum will ask about the key's fingerprint the first time):

```
yum install tor
```

Start Tor using:

```
service tor start
```

Now Tor is installed and running.

More info at https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en

Answer (score 0):

This Reply might be late but it will be helpful. 
I also have installed CentOS. For installing tor follow the steps:

1. open terminal
2. run the following command
   *yum install tor*
3. open **"firefox -> tools -> Add-ons"** on top right corner of the page you will see **search all add-ons** type **foxyproxy** in search results you will see **FoxyProxy Basic 3.2.3** in-front of this you will find **Install** button click on it.
4. After successful installation restart the browser.
5. Infront of address bar you will see an icon of orange fox having cross on it. **Left Click** on icon.
6. In **proxy** tab click on **add new proxy**. a new page will open now click on **proxy details** **check mark** the **Manual proxy configuration** and **socks proxy**. for **Host or ip address** enter **localhost** and for **port** enter **9050**. Click **ok** and then **close**.
7. Now Right Click the fox icon again and check mark the **use proxy localhost:9050
   for all urls**.

BE sure that TOR service is running. open terminal and type "service tor start".

You are secure to surf now... :)